# awk error with indice when used in a loop

Tags: linux, parsing, loops, indices

I have the follwing situation.

```
 awk '$0 != "Force for tool binder"   # print all lines until string found
 $0 =="Force for tool binder"{
 print ; getline ; print;            # go to 2 lines below the string
 getline; getline < " forceState$j.k "; print}' dynaFile_Offen1.k > tempDynaFile.k   # take the string from 
 #the file forceStates$j.k and replace in the main file, generating a temp file.
```

The problem is that here the j is a loop index, meaning that for the first case it is j=1.
     when I used it as forceStates1.k it works perfect but in the loop it is not taking the value.

I would be obliged for the suggestions.

Comment: @kev it is a logical error and not the syntax error. I mean to say , it do nothing with this command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`$j`** in **`'... " forceState$j.k " ...'`** will not get expanded.
Is it a problem?

Comment: @ kev yes, I am of the view that it is not getting expanded.

Comment: so in that case what to do? I have to get the values each time from the new forceStates$j.k

Comment: You can pass variable to awk by using the `-v j=$j` option. And change `"forceState$j.k"` to `"forceState" j ".k"`

Answer (score 0):

The $j looks to be a shell script variable. As your awk script is within a single quoted section the shell will not substitute variables within the awk script. So awk is seeing a literal `$j`. You need to change the shell quoting to permit substitution or probably more usefully pass it in on the command line eg:

```
awk -v loopctr=$j 'BEGIN {print loopctr}'
```

will print your loop counter each time as the value of `j` was passed in the awk variable `loopctr` here.